# nfs mount access denied using Ubuntu 18.04 Vmware client and OSX Sierra host

Tags: macos, ubuntu, mount, vmware-fusion, nfs

I'm trying to nfs share a directory from my OSX machine to be mounted by an Ubuntu client (VM). I feel like I'm missing something in regards to access permissions.  When I try to mount the nfs share, I get an error about access being denied.  I can ssh between both machines, but am having no luck with nfs.

OSX ip is xxx.xxx.xx.xxx and Ubuntu is yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy

OSX /etc/exports:

```
/Users/MichaelHackman/C -alldirs -mapall=501
```

OSX /etc/hosts.allow:

```
ALL: yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
```

On linux:

```
$showmount -e xxx.xxx.xx.xxx
Export list for xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:
/Users/MichaelHackman/C (everyone)

$sudo mkdir -p /nfs/C
$sudo mount -vvvvv xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:/Users/MichaelHackman/C /nfs/C
mount.nfs: timeout set for Thu Jun 21 18:16:17 2018
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.2,addr=xxx.xxx.xx.xxx,clientaddr=yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Protocol not supported
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.1,addr=xxx.xxx.xx.xxx,clientaddr=yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Protocol not supported
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.0,addr=xxx.xxx.xx.xxx,clientaddr=yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Protocol not supported
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'addr=xxx.xxx.xx.xxx'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying xxx.xxx.xx.xxx prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: trying xxx.xxx.xx.xxx prog 100005 vers 3 prot UDP port 760
mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:/Users/MichaelHackman/C
```

On OSX while trying the mount:

```
$ sudo log stream --level debug --parent 1921
    Stream 'nfsd' (1921) owned by 'root' (0)
    Timestamp                       Thread     Type        Activity             PID    
    2018-06-21 21:02:59.848476-0400 0x1db78    Default     0x0                  1921   nfsd: (libsystem_trace.dylib) Add Mode: 0x1000B ( info, debug, stream, propagate w/activity ), Final: 0x1000B ( info, debug, stream, propagate w/activity )
    2018-06-21 21:03:02.066876-0400 0xd087     Activity    0x800000000000baf5   1542   vmware-vmx: (CoreFoundation) GetItemCount
    2018-06-21 21:03:02.066933-0400 0xd087     Info        0x800000000000baf5   1542   vmware-vmx: (CoreFoundation) [com.apple.CFPasteboard.entry] GetItemCount('Apple CFPasteboard general' gen: -1) current-gen: 73
    2018-06-21 21:03:02.066999-0400 0xd087     Info        0x800000000000baf5   1542   vmware-vmx: (CoreFoundation) [com.apple.CFPasteboard.exit] result: 0 gen: 73 count: 0 (from cache)
    2018-06-21 21:03:03.262495-0400 0x1db8c    Debug       0x0                  1921   nfsd: NFS IPv4 socket accepted from xxx.xxx.xx.xxx
    2018-06-21 21:03:03.264093-0400 0x1db8c    Debug       0x0                  1921   nfsd: NFS IPv4 socket accepted from xxx.xxx.xx.xxx
    2018-06-21 21:03:03.265858-0400 0x1db8c    Debug       0x0                  1921   nfsd: NFS IPv4 socket accepted from xxx.xxx.xx.xxx
    2018-06-21 21:03:03.269395-0400 0x1db8c    Debug       0x0                  1921   nfsd: NFS IPv4 socket accepted from xxx.xxx.xx.xxx
    2018-06-21 21:03:05.477757-0400 0xa473     Activity    0x800000000000b92e   1306   VMware Fusion: (CoreFoundation) BeginGeneration
    2018-06-21 21:03:05.477785-0400 0xa473     Info        0x800000000000b92e   1306   VMware Fusion: (CoreFoundation) [com.apple.CFPasteboard.general] Begining new generation for 'Apple CFPasteboard general' why: 'general' old: (changeCount: 181, gen: 73) new: (changeCount: 182, gen: 74) owner-pid: 1306
    2018-06-21 21:03:05.477820-0400 0xa473     Activity    0x800000000000b92f   1306   VMware Fusion: (CoreFoundation) GetItemCount
    2018-06-21 21:03:05.477848-0400 0xa473     Info        0x800000000000b92f   1306   VMware Fusion: (CoreFoundation) [com.apple.CFPasteboard.entry] GetItemCount('Apple CFPasteboard general' gen: 74) current-gen: 74
    2018-06-21 21:03:05.477904-0400 0xa473     Info        0x800000000000b92f   1306   VMware Fusion: (CoreFoundation) [com.apple.CFPasteboard.exit] result: 0 gen: 74 count: 0 (from cache)
    2018-06-21 21:03:23.129686-0400 0xd087     Activity    0x800000000000baf6   1542   vmware-vmx: (CoreFoundation) GetItemCount
    2018-06-21 21:03:23.129759-0400 0xd087     Info        0x800000000000baf6   1542   vmware-vmx: (CoreFoundation) [com.apple.CFPasteboard.entry] GetItemCount('Apple CFPasteboard general' gen: -1) current-gen: 74
    2018-06-21 21:03:23.129845-0400 0xd087     Info        0x800000000000baf6   1542   vmware-vmx: (CoreFoundation) [com.apple.CFPasteboard.exit] result: 0 gen: 74 count: 0 (from cache)
    2018-06-21 21:03:28.738413-0400 0x1db8c    Debug       0x0                  1921   nfsd: NFS IPv4 socket accepted from xxx.xxx.xx.xxx
    2018-06-21 21:03:28.740008-0400 0x1db8c    Debug       0x0                  1921   nfsd: NFS IPv4 socket accepted from xxx.xxx.xx.xxx
    2018-06-21 21:03:28.741281-0400 0x1db8c    Debug       0x0                  1921   nfsd: NFS IPv4 socket accepted from xxx.xxx.xx.xxx
    2018-06-21 21:03:28.744636-0400 0x1db8c    Debug       0x0                  1921   nfsd: NFS IPv4 socket accepted from xxx.xxx.xx.xxx
    2018-06-21 21:03:31.013403-0400 0xcf4      Activity    0x800000000000ba69   386    SystemUIServer: (SystemConfiguration) accessing SCDynamicStore
    2018-06-21 21:03:31.013561-0400 0x281      Activity    0x800000000000bdc5   63     configd: processing SCDynamicStore notification
    2018-06-21 21:03:31.013617-0400 0x281      Activity    0x800000000000bdc6   63     configd: (SystemConfiguration) accessing SCDynamicStore
    2018-06-21 21:03:32.796040-0400 0xa473     Activity    0x800000000000bdd0   1306   VMware Fusion: (CoreFoundation) BeginGeneration
    2018-06-21 21:03:32.796067-0400 0xa473     Info        0x800000000000bdd0   1306   VMware Fusion: (CoreFoundation) [com.apple.CFPasteboard.general] Begining new generation for 'Apple CFPasteboard general' why: 'general' old: (changeCount: 182, gen: 74) new: (changeCount: 183, gen: 75) owner-pid: 1306
    2018-06-21 21:03:32.796096-0400 0xa473     Activity    0x800000000000bdd1   1306   VMware Fusion: (CoreFoundation) GetItemCount
    2018-06-21 21:03:32.796114-0400 0xa473     Info        0x800000000000bdd1   1306   VMware Fusion: (CoreFoundation) [com.apple.CFPasteboard.entry] GetItemCount('Apple CFPasteboard general' gen: 75) current-gen: 75
    2018-06-21 21:03:32.796134-0400 0xa473     Info        0x800000000000bdd1   1306   VMware Fusion: (CoreFoundation) [com.apple.CFPasteboard.exit] result: 0 gen: 75 count: 0 (from cache)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is trying to get this to work, use VMware Fusion's "Shared Folders" functionality instead and make it easy on yourself.

Comment: I came across the same error, and answered here: https://superuser.com/questions/657439/nfs-from-macos-to-centos-in-virtualbox/1518428#1518428. NFS works :-) Shared folders have other limitations, when it comes to symbolic links and more...